# Auth0: Unable to login after signup in universal lock - server_error (Unable to correlate completed consent.)

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, auth0, express-openid-connect

I am unable to login after signup using Universal Lock using `express-id-connect` npm module and getting error.

Step 1. Trying to signup
[image]

Step 2. Consent screen
[image]

Step 3. After granting consent screen getting **server_error (Unable to correlate completed consent.)**
[image]

This is my authentication middleware -

```js
const { auth } = require('express-openid-connect');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');

// Load all environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '..', '.env') });

module.exports = auth({
    authRequired: false,
    auth0Logout: true,

    issuerBaseURL: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL, 
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL, 
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, 
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    idpLogout: true,

    // Define the grant flow
    authorizationParams: {
        response_type: 'code',
        audience: process.env.AUDIENCE,
        scope: 'openid profile email read:notes'
    }
});
```

after adding audience, I get this error **server_error (Unable to correlate completed consent.)**, but when I remove the audience the access token is not generated properly.

How can I fix this error.